# Emotion's CSS props not working with Create-React-App

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, emotion

I wanted to use Emotion with CRA so I installed it following the documentation and tried to use the css prop as shown in the example below :

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { TypographyProps } from "./Typography.propTypes";
import * as styles from "./Typography.styles";

export const Typography: FC<TypographyProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  return <h1 css={styles.typography}>{children}</h1>;
};
```

but it didn't work.

By inspecting the code, I found this :

```
<h1 css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. 
It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), 
but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).">
Header</h1>
```

I tried following the solution from this blog article, but still didn't work :
https://harryhedger.medium.com/quick-how-to-use-the-emotion-css-prop-with-create-react-app-5f6aa0f0c5c5

Any thing I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to add the following line at the beginning of your file.

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
```

Comment: It worked! thank you very much, I would have upvoted your answer, however, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hello, can you explain what it does?

Comment: @Monstar in order to use the css prop with TypeScript, you have to configure the JSX transform and the jsxImportSource TSConfig options. It a required setup, as written in emotion docs: https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#emotionreact

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Emotion docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#emotionreact):

> in order to use the css prop with TypeScript you have to configure the
> new `JSX transform` and the `jsxImportSource` TSConfig options
> (available since TS 4.1). For this approach, your TSConfig
> `compilerOptions` should contain:

```
"jsx": "react-jsx",
"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
```

For most users, this is a required setup.